# dynamically added column in gridview at right most place

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my code.

```
hitechLatestEntities database = new hitechLatestEntities();
GridView1.DataSource = database.HEADs;

TemplateField tfObject = new TemplateField();
tfObject.HeaderText = "Sub-Heads Details";

tfObject.ItemTemplate = new WebForm1(ListItemType.Item);
GridView1.Columns.Add(tfObject);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I want this recently added column at right most place of the gridview1. For now it is appearing at left most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, tfObject);
```

instead of `GridView1.Columns.Add(tfObject);`. This inserts your column at the index 0 instead of at the end. This will cause it to render as first column.

Comment: when i change index other than 0 it gives me following error: 
"Insertion index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than or equal to size."
gridview have 3 columns but this insert() is not even working with index 1 or 2.

Comment: Are you sure you have already 3 columns in there when this line of code gets hit? Maybe you should call DataBind() before you insert your column.

Comment: ofcourse there are 3 of them. i called databind before insert but even then it is showing same error.